# Как изменить последовательность байт в бинарном файле?

Tags: c, файлы

Как можно изменить определённую последовательность байт в бинарном файле. Пробовал открывать файл с модификатором "r+b", сместить указатель функцией `fseek` и функцией `fwrite` записать, это не помогло а только добавило новый блок байт

Comment: А ничего что "r" в вашем "r+b" это про read? А вам писать в файл надо...

Comment: Вам нужно просто записать поверх, или считать, модифицировать и записать обратно?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов `r` - это чтение, а `r+` - чтение и запись

Comment: А вы бы кусочек кода не показали? КАК вы это делаете?

Comment: "... это не помогло а только добавило новый блок байт". Это лишь значит, что вы сделали `fseek` в конец файла. Что попросили - то и получили.